# Is Flutter just for UI development?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart

In Flutter's official web page, Flutter is described as below:

"Flutter is Google’s UI toolkit for building beautiful, natively compiled applications for mobile, web, and desktop from a single codebase."

My question is
1. Is it just for cross-platform UIs?
2. If it is, then how can you integrate with data models and all hardware features?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flutter is not just a framework that you can build great UI with. It uses the programming language Dart and the code is compiled to native platform code. It's not just for UI development as Google uses Flutter to make some of its applications like Stadia. Other companies like the New York Times build their apps with Flutter and those apps have functionality and they're entirely built with the Flutter framework.

So back to your question. It's not just for building beautiful UI's. Even in the documentation, it says:

> natively compiled applications

So you can use Flutter to make cross-platform, native applications, not just for UI. It supports popular things like Redux, BLoC pattern, and many more for the reactivity of your app.

I recommend you take a look [here](https://flutter.dev/showcase) to see some of the apps fully built with just the Flutter framework.

Comment: Thank you!! Now I understand what it is :)

Answer (score 0):

Flutter is UI plus business logic which means frontend, hence **Flutter is a frontend SDK**. Many people say that Dart is used for backend, but that’s not true, Dart is purely used for frontend logic and Flutter is indeed, 100% frontend. But…**native Android and native iOS development too are “just” frontend**, purely.

Because, the server side logic of any app is written using a backend language/framework which is not a responsibility for a frontend person (Android, iOS, Flutter or any other developer). Backend technologies to be used always depends on the company’s preferences. And remember, writing your backend in either of these frontend languages is not good for long-term lifespan of your app, most companies are not stupid, that they don’t use Kotlin or Dart or Swift in the backend to save money, they know that, ultimately, doing that will cost them even more than hiring backend devs separately because it is very rare (almost impossible) to find expert people who can code backends in Dart/Kotlin/Swift.

While JS has many existing, widely adopted stacks for backend, so the above is not same for web devs, they’ll be paid more for being a full-stack person.